# Bind mounts in docker compose won't synchronize local changes into container automatically on Mac M1

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, apple-m1

So I was working on a Macbook (with intel chip) and used the django-cookie-cutter template to start my project. Everything was working fine there.

I then switched to a new mac with apple chip. Now my changes on host machine are not replicated in the docker container i.e the container is not restarted automatically.

In my docker file, I have a 'docs' container which does restart on changes, but for the django container, I have to stop it manually with `cmd+c` and then restart it for my changes to take effect.

Here's my local.yml (docker compose) file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  papersdb_local_postgres_data: {}
  papersdb_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: papersdb_local_django
    container_name: papersdb_local_django
    platform: linux/x86_64
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /app
    working_dir: /app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: papersdb_production_postgres
    container_name: papersdb_local_postgres
    volumes:
      - papersdb_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - papersdb_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"

  docs:
    image: papersdb_local_docs
    container_name: papersdb_local_docs
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./papersdb:/app/papersdb:z
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: /start-docs
```

Here's the bind mount in result of `docker inspect my_container_name`:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/Users/mazhar.ali/Projects/PapersDB/papersdb",
        "Destination": "/app",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

I also have another project with celery and celerybeat, both of them restart on changes too. It's just the django container that's creating issues.

I had backed up my mac into another drive with 'Time Machine'. Then reinstalled docker desktop and reinstalled it (since the old one wasn't working on the new chip), which deleted all the containers and volumes. I am not sure if it has something to do with that.

Comment: The issue for me was runserver_plus. When I changed the docker file to run django with only 'python manage.py runserver'. It worked.

Comment: What I found is, it is syncing but it takes some time